# SQL Two tables two primary keys how to connect them?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and two primary keys.I want when one of the users.id count++ the other user_personal_data.id to do the same and both id to be the same.How to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE monster.users(
id         INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
username    VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
email       VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
password    VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
role        VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE monster.user_personal_data(
user_id     INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
fname       VARCHAR(256),
lname       VARCHAR(256),
city        VARCHAR(256),
age         VARCHAR(256),
education   VARCHAR(256)
);
```

Comment: Change your design. Either use only 1 table with all the columns from both tables, or make user_id of user_personal_data a foreign key to id of users.

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag as the syntax is MySql

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to implement a trigger, as such:

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_inserted ON monster.users AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO monster.user_personal_data (user_id)
    SELECT id
    FROM inserted
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right your design, table `user_personal_data` expand table `users`. 
In this design only one (main) table can have aoutoincrement column. In your case it should be column `id` in `users` table. 
Second table `user_personal_data` must have foreign key linked it to main table.
So your tables should to have next structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_personal_data` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `education` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_personal_data_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
```

For save table consistent you can use trigger on `AFTER INSERT` on table `users` like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER users_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON users FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO monster.user_personal_data (user_id) VALUES (NEW.id)
```

The solution given in MySQL syntax. Each over RDBMS nay have different syntax.